# Contradiction in row-column operations

Tags: matrices

Have been doing some matrix row-column operations and came across a contradiction that I can't understand where my thinking has gone wrong.

So, I understand that you can factor a common ratio from a row and this scales the determinant by said factor

$$\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix} = 2\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix} = 2 $$

Furthermore, I know you can multiply a row by a constant and this scales the determinant by said constant

$$\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix} = \frac12 \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix} = \frac 12$$

This yields the contradiction that $$2 = \frac 12$$

This is cleary incorrect.

So, where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said "you can multiply a row by a constant and this scales the determinant by said constant", which is correct, but that isn't what the math you did in the next line was. The math version of that claim would be

$$\left|\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right| = \frac12\left|\begin{array}{cc}2&2\\0&1\end{array}\right| = 1$$

which is perfectly correct and compatible with your previous observation. The key here is that the phrase **multiply a row by a constant** means that you are changing the matrix you're talking about; contrast with "factor a common ratio from a row", which means modifying the matrix in place.

To take an example from more elementary mathematics, recall the principle *you can factor a common ratio out of the components of a sum, scaling the result by that factor.* This means that, for example,

$$2 + 2 = 2(1 + 1) = 2 \cdot 2 = 4$$

Likewise, *you can multiply both components of a sum by a constant, scaling the result by that constant.*

$$1 + 1 = 2$$

$$\frac12 + \frac12 = \frac12\cdot2 = 1$$

These two principles are not in conflict, they're just applied in different ways. The first allows us to modify a sum in-place so that another sum appears as part of the calculation; the second allows us to modify an old sum to create a new sum. The same thing is going on in your examples.

Comment: I'm still confused by your first point. It seems you have multiplied the first row by 2, yet have scaled the determinant by 1/2?

Comment: The "original" matrix in that example is the one with 2's at the top. That equation expresses the sentiment that multiplying the first row by 1/2 (producing the matrix on the left) yields the same determinant as multiplying the original determinant by 1/2 (producing the expression in the middle).

Comment: Oh okay, I now understand. Thanks so much for your help.